# Is is possible to rebuild wp_term_relationships table?

Tags: tags

Stupidly, I truncated my posts table with out thinking about the term relationships. Now I have a bunch of 404s because there are broken term relationships. Is is possible to rebuild the table with the correct pairings?

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. If you truncated your posts table what is there to rebuild? Why can't you just truncate your `wp_term_relationships` table?

Comment: @totels I truncated the wp_posts table but I didn't truncate wp_term_relationships. Its looking like I'm going to have to rebuild the entire blog

Comment: Are you saying that you truncated `wp_posts` long ago and have already started entering new posts?

Comment: @totels yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `AUTO_INCREMENT` value wasn't reset and your new posts will still have unique `ID`s and you can do:

```
SELECT tr.*, p.ID
FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS p ON tr.object_id = p.ID
WHERE p.ID is NULL;
```

to see which term relationships are orphans and use a `DELETE FROM` to fix it.

Comment: Or if you prefer a nested select: `SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts);`

Comment: thank you for your attempt. unfortunatly it returned 0 results. It apears that my auto_increment was indeed reset.

Comment: Even if your auto_increment was reset it is unlikely you would get 0 results unless you now have more posts than you did before you truncated. What is the output of the `Auto_Increment` field when you run `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_posts';`? As compared to `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM wp_posts;`?

Comment: i dumped the wp_term_relationships table and rebuild the tags. Luckily the tagging was generated by a script i wrote so it was easy to re tag my posts. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble it might be helpful to someone later if you would share your solution.

Comment: updated with solution below

Answer (score 1):

**warning:** Truncating your wp_term_relationships deletes everything in that table! if you want to only delete tag term relationships then make sure you use the correct sql.

After truncating the wp_term_relationships table I used a custom script to re-tag my posts. You can do something similar like this:

```
$numposts = wp_count_posts();
$posts = get_posts(array('numberposts'=>(int)$numposts->publish));
foreach($posts as $post){
    $tags = myCustomTaggingFunc($post); //this returns an array of tags
    wp_update_term($post->ID,$tags);
}
```

pretty simple.

Comment: `wp_update_term` takes the term id as first argument, how do you use `$post->ID` instead